# error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Contact'. Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-services

I want to run my project to save contact in my front End i was read this mistacle in my IDE webStorm **ERROR in src/app/new-contact/new-contact.component.ts(24,9): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Contact'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'Object'.**

In the line new-contact.component.ts(24,9) **(at .subscribe((data))** i has this code

```
saveContact(){
this.contactService.saveContact(this.contact)
  .subscribe((data)  => {
    this.contact = data;
    this.mode = 2;
  }, err=>{
    console.log("ErReUr : "+err);
  });
```

}

And i have the code of service

```
saveContact(contact: Contact){
return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/addPerson", contact);
}
```

And i have a my class in the project but in a file in the project and this is the code

```
export class Contact {
   any = null;
   nom: string = '';
   prenom: string = '';
   email: string = '';
   tel: number = 0;
   photo: string = '';
   dateNAissance:Date;
 }
```

the problem is in the id of the **Contact** and in the Object

Help me i want a solution and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write your service as such:

```
saveContact(contact: Contact){
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/addPerson", contact) as Observable<Contact>;
}
```

I.E. return it as an Observable of type Contact.